# When was statistics used in psychology research first?

Tags: history-of-psychology

I am wondering about the origin of statistics' usage in psychology. Psychology was rooted in philosophy. At that time there were no experiments and analysing the data, but I guess that there must be the very first time when someone came up with the idea to use statistics in the analysis. (and that's my question).

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](http://140.116.183.121/~sheu/xpDesign/Articles/aHistoricalViewOfStatisticalConcepts.pdf) suggests it was a psychophysics experiment by Fencher in 1860.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1085417?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents Is this the right link for the resource you mentioned?